# QGIS - Hide local drives Group Policy

Tags: qgis-browser

QGIS doesn't comply with a Group Policy set to hide local drives for my users.
How can I hide the local drive within the QGIS browser?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on a drive in the QGIS browser you have the option to hide it (you also have the option to see and restore hidden item, so nothing will prevent user to restore what you have hidden)....

[image]

Comment: Ok, this feels like a workaround. I would expect to see QGIS follow the restrictions that are applied to the machine. Thank you anyway.